# how to call java -jar from rpgle

Tags: java, jar, rpgle

I try to call a java main from rpgle program. I have set directory and classpath correctly and I actually managed to call java method/main from a .class file.

However, I have no clue at all on how to call a main method from a .jar file in rpgle. This is what I get from error message:

```
"received Java exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:          
 com.tl.TL" when calling method "main" with signature
 "([Ljava.lang.String;)V" in class "com/tl/TL".
```

Appreciate someone could show me the light in the tunnel.... Thank you!

Comment: I have used RPG to invoke methods in jar files - Scott Klement's POI wrappers are a good example.  I have never tried invoking a main method but I don't see why it would be any different.  To help clarify your question, did you simply JAR the .class file and try to invoke it from RPG?  Could you post your RPG and Java definitions?  Is the .jar file in your CLASSPATH?  You can specify the CLASSPATH as /javafolder/* and it will find all .jar files in /javafolder.

Comment: You are right, Calabro! It works! I accidentally specify ";" instead of ":" for the .jar directory in my CLASSPATH... Thank you for your comment. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLASSPATH no doubt is a sensitive matter... Defining a correct CLASSPATH will determine 50% of the succeed of executing a working program.